# Deleted file during rebase, how can I get it back?

Tags: git, rebase

I was going through a rebase, and accidentally deleted one of my files.

When I try to get it back via `git checkout` it tells me

```
error: path 'foo' is unmerged
```

When I try to get it back via `git reset foo`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'foo': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

How can I get my file back?

Answer (score 1):

The "path is unmerged" error suggests that you haven't just deleted a file, but have some kind of conflict with it. If, however, you can manage to get to a clean working tree and index (`git status` shows no output except maybe some untracked files), and if you still don't have your file named "foo", then pick a commit, say HEAD~5, that has "foo" in the state you want, and `git checkout HEAD~5 -- foo`.

Comment: Helpful tip, Catherine can use `git show HEAD~5:foo` to look at that state of the file.

Comment: @basicxman: Helpful indeed, but it needs a colon: `git show HEAD~5:foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that the conflict thing is correct--there were merge conflicts within it that I had to resolve, except then instead of checking it in I removed it (that's what I get for holding a conversation while rebasing). The problem is that now I can't rebase because I can't `git add` add a nonexistent file. Should I just `git rm` it and then retrieve it later? Will that affect my rebase adversely?

Comment: Maybe the simplest thing is just to remove it, reset it, and check it back out. I.e. `git rm foo` to stage removal and wipe out the conflict, `git reset foo` to unstage it, and then `git checkout HEAD~5 -- foo` to get your preferred version of it. Of course, this will lose the changes being introduced by the rebase at this point. I'm not sure that there's a way to recover those without restarting the rebase, since you've already removed the file with the conflict markers.